# Passing a boolean value to asp.net api controller via Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-apicontroller

I am trying to pass a single `boolean` value via `ajax` to a `server API`.
The API action is hitted but the parameter (shuffled) is `false`, though I am setting it to true via `Ajax`.

**The api controller action is this:**

```
[HttpPost("PostShuffled")]
public IActionResult PostShuffled([FromBody]bool shuffled)
{
    userSession.Shuffled = shuffled;
    return Ok();
}
```

**My Ajax call is this:**

```
function ChangeViewMode(el) {
    if (el.id == "ViewShuffled") {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/Data/PostShuffled",
            contentType: "application/json",
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({ shuffled: true }),
            success: function () { alert("ok"); }
        });
    }
}
```

My question is what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have solved the problem this way:

Defined a new class:

```
 public class AjaxShuffled
    {
        public bool shuffled { get; set; }
    }
```

Then in my controller changed:

```
[HttpPost("PostShuffled")]
    public IActionResult PostShuffled([FromBody]AjaxShuffled s)
    {
        userSession.Shuffled = s.shuffled;
        return Ok();
    }
```

And now the value is passed correctly. I had to encapsulate the boolean into a class to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `shuffled` is wrapped in an object instead of sent by itself. If you only want to send a boolean value, just send `true` or `false` itself: `data: true` or `data: JSON.stringify(true)` depending on how you've configured your web service to handle input formats for boolean. On the server side you should only need the [FromBody] descriptor on the API method parameter.